# MDT: choose specific partition to install Windows on

Tags: partition, mdt, mdt-2013

For several reasons I need to be able to customize MDT, so that I can choose which partition I want to install Windows on. We already have this option when we install from a simple Windows DVD, so why is it so hard to implement this into MDT?

Any suggestions on how I can proceed?

Comment: Could you say what version of MDT you are using?
Also there will be a tag for that version.

Comment: I use MDT 2013 (mdt-2013 tag wasn't available for me)

Comment: Oh, yah I had forgotten about the lack of the tag...

Comment: If I have answered you question please mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 5):

You can select what partition/disk you apply Windows to by going to the task sequence and selecting your install operating system task.

[image]

After you select it you will notice that there is a section (under the "Operating system to install:" selection box) that allows you to define where the OS will be installed to.

My installation automatically collects the drive letter from the disk format stage and apples to the primary disk automatically (to whatever drive letter the primary disk is mounted to).

[image]
Hope this helps!

Comment: How does your solution collect the correct drive letter in the format stage? The correct drive in our case would be a partition on the primary disk, that either had Windows installed already, or was made available using a partition manager. I have tried to use a file explorer (from DaRT), rename the correct partition (i.e. "WinOS"), and then point to this name in the format stage and set the variable here as well to be ready for the installation stage. But it didn't work.

We need this because some users have either data partition or dualboot on the primary disk.

Comment: I will update the answer

Comment: Thanks again, but this procedure will wipe the whole disk 0 and all partitions on it. I am considering to test another way:
I will create several txt files for each possible partition (probably max. 4). The txt files will have code for DiskPart, each wiping and formatting that specific partition. Then create a Task Seq. for each and call them in the Format section like this:
1: diskpart /s "%scriptroot%\DiskPartOnlyPar1.txt"
2: diskpart /s "%scriptroot%\DiskPartOnlyPar2.txt"
etc.
This way I can choose a TS that correspond to the partition, I want to install to. I will give it a try.

Comment: Can you tell me what setup you need? I can replicate it in the configuration system...

Comment: Do you still want help with this?