# How to manually select a specific disk in the UDI Wizard when using MDT 2013?

Tags: hard-drive, wds, mdt-2013

Is there a way to manually select a disk or partition as part of the MDT Deployment UDI Wizard rather than MDT automatically selecting one.

I know you can select one in the Task Sequence but I'm specifically looking for a way to do this in the wizard.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Joshua

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MDT: choose specific partition to install Windows on](http://serverfault.com/questions/612932/mdt-choose-specific-partition-to-install-windows-on)

Comment: Can you specify your question that you want the user to select the partition or disk letter inside the Udi wizard. Thanks!

Comment: TLDR:  I would like to have an option to manually select the disk/partition as part of the MDT Deployment UDI Wizard rather than MDT automatically selecting it.

Comment: I am sorry I meant by editing the original question. People tend to not read the comments for extra info for the question. They tend to read it for extra info / context for the answer or how the answer was arrived at.

Comment: I updated the Question to be shorter, and more to the point.  Hopefully it's also more clear what I'm asking for ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately MDT does not have a wizard page for what you want to accomplish.

We are going to need to create one.

Below are some great links to help you build your own UDI page(s).

---

### Links:

- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mniehaus/2012/08/01/mdt-2012-update-1-udi-build-your-own-pages/
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25739.integrating-udi-into-your-sccm-osd-task-sequences.aspx
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn781090.aspx

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Thanks for the resources links, I will hopefully review them over the next few days when I get back to this project.

Answer (score 0):

In MDT (Microsoft Deployment Toolkit) 2013, the UDI (User-Driven Installation) Wizard allows users to interactively select options during deployment, including selecting a specific disk to install the operating system. Here's how you can manually select a specific disk in the UDI Wizard:

1. Open the Deployment Workbench:

Launch the Deployment Workbench on the MDT server or the computer where you have MDT installed.

2. Navigate to the Deployment Share:

Expand the "Deployment Shares" node in the left pane and navigate to your specific deployment share that contains the task sequence you want to modify.

3. Open the Task Sequence:

Expand the "Task Sequences" node, and then locate and open the task sequence you want to modify using the UDI Wizard.

4. Configure the UDI Wizard:

In the task sequence editor, locate and click on the "User Driven Installation (UDI)" step in the task sequence. This step is usually named "Gather local only" or "Gather" (depending on your MDT version).

5. Enable the "Specify custom disk layout" option:

Within the UDI Wizard step properties, find the "Specify custom disk layout" option, and set it to "YES." This will enable the feature that allows users to manually select a specific disk during deployment.

6. Save the changes:

Click "OK" or "Apply" to save the changes you made to the UDI Wizard step.

7. Update the deployment share:

After making changes to the task sequence, remember to update the deployment share to apply the modifications.

Now, when you deploy a system using this task sequence, the UDI Wizard will prompt you to select a specific disk on which to install the operating system. You will be presented with a list of available disks along with their details (such as disk size and model) to help you make the correct selection. Be cautious when choosing the disk, as the data on the selected disk may be erased during the deployment process.

Keep in mind that MDT 2013 is an older version, and newer versions of MDT or other deployment solutions may have slightly different steps or methods for achieving the same goal.